# Derivative of matrix inner product

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus

Let $A$ be a matrix with no restrictions, then I can compute,

$$\nabla_x (x^t Ax) = \nabla_x (\sum_{i,j}x_i A_{ij} x_j) = Ax+A_Nx$$
Where $A_N$ is equal to $A$ on its diagonal entries and zero everywhere else.

Now suppose $B$ is symmetric, positive definite, and tridiagonal. I saw in a lecture that,

$$\nabla_x (x^t Bx) = 2Bx$$

I can see that this result would be true if $B$ were diagonal, but not otherwise. Am I making a bad mistake or is this incorrect?

Comment: $\frac{\partial(x^TAx)}{\partial(x)}$ should be $Ax+A^Tx$

Comment: You're right... my computation was bad.

Comment: How is that related to matrix inner products?

Answer (score 2):

You should check this out for a short summary:
http://www.empirical.economics.uni-mainz.de/Dateien/nice_little_derivatives.pdf

In order for the mentioned results to hold $B$ does only have to be symmetric, not necessarily diagonal.

Comment: That link has stopped working.